# Decimal repunits of order greater than 2 do not have repunits in any other base

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures

This is a proof of a special case of `[Goormaghtigh's conjecture][1]`,namely

$$\frac{10^m-1}{10-1} = \frac{y^n-1}{y-1}$$
 satisfying $10>y>1$  and $ n,m >2 $
has no non-trivial solution in non-negative integers.

Proof:

$$\frac{10^{m-1}-1}{10-1}.\frac{10}{y} = \frac{y^{n-1}-1}{y-1}$$

$\therefore10 |y$ or $(10^{m-1}-1)|y\ \because \frac{y^{n-1}-1}{y-1}$  is in  naturals set.

$$\implies y = 2,3,5,9,I_{m-2}$$

By observation, $ y \neq I_{m-2}$

Case 1 $ y = 9$

$$\implies\frac{10^m-1}{10-1} = \frac{9^n-1}{8} $$

$$\implies \ 8*10^m = 9^{n+1}-1$$

It is easy to see that this has no solution for the given conditions

$\therefore \  y \neq 3$

Case  2 $ y = 5$

$$\implies\frac{10^m-1}{10-1} = \frac{5^n-1}{4} $$

$$\implies \ 4*10^m = 9*5^n-5$$

$$\implies \ 8*10^{m-1} = 9*5^{n-1}-1$$

It is easy to see that this has no solution for the given conditions

Case 3 $ y = 2 $

$$\implies\frac{10^m-1}{10-1} = 2^n-1 $$

Similarly  for case 3

Hence proved

I understand that there is not much detail regarding the 'it is easy to show', but I have merely posted the proof sketch to know if my strategies work.

I am a high schooler and am not fluent in mathematical proof-writing. I understand that there could be flaws or misunderstanding and will be more than glad to receive opinion/feedback/advice on this proof attempt

PS $I_{m-2}$ is the repunit of order $m-2$ where the repunit of order $3$ is $111$ and so on

Looking at this I see that I made a fatal flaw not considering prime factors of $I_{m-2}$

Comment: What is $x$ ? The base on the left is $10$, hence $x=10$ ?

Comment: In the very first line of the proof, you multiply the left- hand side by $\frac{10}y$ and leave the right-hand side unchanged, so it seems you are assuming $10=y$, which is what you want to prove.

Comment: No, the rhs is not unchanged. It is $\frac{y^{n-1}-1}{y-1}$ and neither is the LHS btw

Comment: @Peter sorry for that, it was a copy paste from goormaghtigh’s conjecture page. Yes x =10

Comment: $$\frac{10^{m-1}-1}{10-1}.\frac{10}{y} = \frac{y^{n-1}-1}{y-1}$$
leads to
$$\frac{10^m-10}{10-1} = \frac{y^n-y}{y-1}$$
which isn't what you started with.

Comment: @nickgard Yes it is $\frac{10^m-10}{10-1} = \frac{10^m -1 -10+1}{10-1} = \frac{10^m-1}{10-1}-1(LHS).....\frac{y^n-y}{y-1}=\frac{y^n-1-y+1}{y-1} = \frac{y^n-1}{y-1}-1$ which are equal by hypothesis